# Azure - Just in Time Access to VM in subscription you don't own

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to setup [Just in Time Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-just-in-time) in Azure, so I have an account  with subscription where I've enabled Security Center Standard edition (required for JIT). I've created there a Resource Group and a VM.

Now I took another account (let's call it a2@foo.com) and I've given it **Reader** privileges on the mentioned **Resource Group** and **Contributor** on **VM** and its **Network Security Group**.

After logging to the portal, a2@foo.com doesn't have access to JIT, because  Subscriptions it owns don't have Security Center Standard enabled - these are separate subscriptions than the one mentioned earlier (so it's not possible to request JIT through the portal).

When I use PowerShell, I am able to select subscription where VM is deployed (`Select-AzureRmSubscription`), I am able to see that there is a JIT policy used there (`Get-ASCJITAccessPolicy`), but when I run `Invoke-ASCJITAccess` I get an error:

`Invoke-ASCJITAccess : JIT VM Access requires a Standard tier subscription. For more info please visit aka.ms/asc-jit`

Am I missing something or Just In Time Access works only on subscriptions you own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Contributor role for user a2@foo.com on the Resource Group solved the problem and this user is able to request JIT Access through PowerShell (not through portal).